# how can i make a simple editor by contenteditable but without execommand

Tags: javascript, editor, contenteditable, editing, execcommand

because execcommand is obsolete : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand.

i do work on a knowledge network, we use a markup language just like markdown, but is more simple than it. so we need a very simple editor in web browser.

we need 3 things in js:

1. add something, just like: document.execCommand('insertText', false, '  ');
2. change something style, maybe this can be implement by pure dom.
3. add tag around something, just like: 
   document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'span');

and in all thing, we want make the caret static on ui, don/t boring the user, avoid the caret error, just like caret lost or jump random  .

and our target webbrowser is chrome, so we can accept some solution that is chrome only.

Comment: execCommand can mostly be replaced with [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection_API) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) APIs.

Comment: @Teemu  thank you, i will learn it.